# how to Use text.LastIndexOf() method in vb

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim strFilename As String = txtImgPath.Text.Substring(txtImgPath.Text.LastIndexOf("\")"+"1)

txtImgPath - (contain e.g C:/file1/file/cat.jpg )
```

there is a problem in me trying to get the last name or the filename after the last " \ " in the url.

I do not know how to what is my code problem. can someone please kindly guide me?
I need help.

Comment: Can you give an example of what will be in `txtImgPath`?

Comment: txtImgPath - (contain e.g C:/file1/file/cat.jpg )

it contain something like this. thank you

I want to get the cat.jpg only. and avoid getting the entire string

Answer (score 2):

Use [System.IO.Path.GetFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
Dim strFilename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(txtImgPath.Text)
```